# Why is program terminating after input() prompt?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

After an input() prompt my program terminates instead of moving on to the while() loops proceeding it which are meant to be executed depending on the input (yes/no). The program terminates after the data_confirmation input prompt.

```
username_prompt = input("Enter your username: ")
line_space = '\n'
print(line_space)

if username_prompt == user1_username:

    print("Bootcamp date: " + user1_bootcamp_date)
    print("Bootcamp venue: " + user1_bootcamp_location)
    print("Bootcamp type: " + user1_bootcamp_type)
    print("Exposure: " + user1_xp)
    print(line_space)

    data_confirmation = input("Please confirm whether the information above is correct (yes/no): ")
    print(line_space)

    while data_confirmation.lower == "yes":
        print("Thank you!")
        break

    while data_confirmation.lower == "no":
        data_correction_prompt = input("Which information is incorrect (e.g Date): ")
        print(line_space)

        if data_correction_prompt.lower == "date":
            bootcamp_date_c = input("Enter the correct date (e.g 4 April): ")
            user1_bootcamp_date = bootcamp_date_c
            print(line_space)
            print("Thank you!")
    
        elif data_correction_prompt.lower == "venue":
            bootcamp_venue_c = input("Enter the correct venue (e.g Johannesburg): ")
            user1_bootcamp_location = bootcamp_venue_c
            print(line_space)
            print("Thank you!")
    
        elif data_correction_prompt.lower == "type":
            bootcamp_type_c = input("Enter the correct type (Physical/Virtual): ")
            user1_bootcamp_type = bootcamp_type_c
            print(line_space)
            print("Thank you!")
    
        elif data_correction_prompt.lower == "exposure":
            bootcamp_xp_c = input ("Enter your experiernce (e.g No prior experience/Prior experience): ")
            user1_xp = bootcamp_xp_c
            print(line_space)
            print("Thank you!")

        else:
            data_correction_prompt = input("Invalid input. Please state date/venue/type/exposure: ")
    
        break
```

Comment: What is user1_username?

Answer (score 0):

As @user2182349 mentioned, you have not shown us the declaration of the variable `user1_username`. Since the input is being compared with that, the while loop will only run if the `username_prompt` is equal to that value.

Perhaps you have forgotten to declare a variable and are comparing it to `undefined`?

Hope this helped :D

Comment: user1_username variable has been declared amongst other unincluded lines of code that come before what you see here. It's from a txt doc read.

Comment: Ah, I must have misunderstood the question. Also, you should mark the other answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

`lower` is a function available to the `string` type. When you invoke `data_confirmation.lower`, you are not calling the `lower` function. Instead, you are referencing the function itself. Being a function, `lower` of course can never itself be equal to the strings `"yes"` or `"no"`. To indicate you are actually calling the function, you must add parentheses: `data_confirmation.lower()`.

Comment: This works! Such a small thing to miss. Well explained too!

Comment: I'm glad this worked for you :D If my answer was helpful, then I'd appreciate it if you marked it as correct, since it helps me out as well